# How to invalidate an URL in Varnish in the way, that old version is still served until new version is cached

Tags: varnish

I'd like to mark a number of URL in Varnish as invalid in some cases from backend and keep them served from cache until the new version is fetched from the backend. From my understanding and experimenting using PURGE does delete the page complete from the cache -- beresp.grace seems to be not honored. Is there any good practice to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use soft purges for that through the [purge VMOD](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/7.4/reference/vmod_purge.html).

Rather than immediately removing the object from the cache, it will expire the object explicitly and will use the grace value to serve stale content while the new version is fetched asynchronously.

Here's the code you need to get it done:

```
vcl 4.1;


import purge;

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.55.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method Not Allowed"));
        }
        return (hash);
    }
}
sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        call my_purge;
    }
}
sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        call my_purge;
    }
}
sub my_purge {
    set req.http.purged = purge.soft(0s,30s,120s);
    if (req.http.purged == "0") {
        return (synth(404));
    } else {
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }
}
```

This code will provide an entrypoint to invalidate content using the `PURGE` request method. To avoid unauthorized access, an ACL was defined that contains a whitelist of IP addresses, subnets and host names.

This example will expire the content and will add 30 seconds of grace time and 120 seconds of keep time.

This means:

- Up to 30 seconds after the expiration time, content stale content will be served while an async fetch is made
- Up to 120 seconds after the grace expires, the object will still be kept around for the sake of conditional requests (`If-None-Match` or `If-Modified-Since`).